# Starts with Vowel Sound

Tags: custom-object

While creating a new custom object there is a checkbox "Starts  with Vowel Sound".Can someone explain me in detail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If it is appropriate for your organization’s default language, check
>   if your label should be preceded by "an" instead of "a."

Quoted directly from the help:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_objectcreate.htm&language=en_US

Comment: You should note, however, that this option will change if the organization's language changes. For example, in Spanish, it becomes "gender", which causes the UI to render "la" (female) or "el" (male), such as "la casa" ("the house") or "el coche" ("the car").

Answer (score 4):

This exists because there are certain parts of the UI that will attempt to place articles in front of names of your objects. Since languages like English and French, German change either the definite or indefinite article of a noun when that noun begins with a vowel, rather than trying to detect proper grammar rules ourselves, we let you tell the system that an object name requires the treatment of starting with a "vowel" with regards to the articles the system attempts to use.

I've never seen a comprehensive list of where we do this article decoration in the UI...I've always presumed reports, and maybe some other configuration pages.

In the end it just becomes something you do when you add an object and typically forget from that point forward.